# i have a question regarding pushing the elements toward the right

Tags: bootstrap-4

So, I am having trouble sending my list to the right side of the page. I do not know what is happening and I tried a bunch of method to solve it but it just would not go to the side of the page.

I used ml-auto to move but it didnt work

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class = "navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light  sticky-top">
    <div class= "cointainer-fluid">
        <a class = "navbar-brand" href= "#"> <img src = "img/lostlog.jpg" id = "brand-image"></a>
        <button class= "navbar-toggler" type = "button" data-toggle = "collaspe" data-taget= "#navbarResponsive">
            <span class= "navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class = "collaspe navbar-collapse" id = "navbarResponsive">
            <ul class ="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class= "nav-item active">
                    <a class = "nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class= "nav-item">
                    <a class = "nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class= "nav-item">
                    <a class = "nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class= "nav-item">
                    <a class = "nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant add container-fluid in `navbar`, by removing that you can achieve your goal.

Replace `collaspe` with `collapse` and `taget` with `target`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class = "navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light  sticky-top">
    <a class = "navbar-brand" href= "#"> <img src = "img/lostlog.jpg" id = "brand-image"></a>
    <button class= "navbar-toggler" type = "button" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target= "#navbarResponsive">
        <span class= "navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "navbarResponsive">
        <ul class ="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class= "nav-item active">
                <a class = "nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class= "nav-item">
                <a class = "nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class= "nav-item">
                <a class = "nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class= "nav-item">
                <a class = "nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```